# Ошибка : Встречено ';', а ожидалось ')'

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Не могу понять, что не так(строка с ошибкой указана)

```
{––––– Зашифровка одного символа –––––}
function Encrypt(arg: char; CKey: integer): char;
var
  x: integer;
begin
  x := Ord(arg) + CKey;
  if x > 255 then x := x - 256 + 32;
  Encrypt := Chr(x);
end;

function Decrypt(arg: char; CKey: integer): char;
var
  x: integer;
begin
  x := Ord(arg) - CKey;
  if x < 32 then x := x + 256 - 32;
  Decrypt := Chr(x);
end;
{––––– Зашифровка строки –––––}
procedure EncryptStr(var arg: string; CKey: integer);
var
  k: integer;
begin
  for k := 1 to Length(arg) do
    arg[k] := Encrypt(arg[k];2); {Тут пишет Встречено ';', а ожидалось ')'}
end;
{––––– Расшифровка строки –––––}
procedure DecryptStr(var arg: string; CKey: integer);
var
  k: integer;
begin
  for k := 1 to Length(arg) do
    arg[k] := Decrypt(arg[k];2);
end;
{––––– Главная программа –––––}
var
  S: string;
  Oper: integer;

begin
  repeat
    Write('Введите строку: '); Readln(S);
    Writeln('Укажите операцию: 1– шифровать,' +
        ' 2– расшифровать,' +
        ' Прочие – выход');
    Readln(Oper);
    case Oper of
      1: EncryptStr(S);
      2: DecryptStr(S);
    else Break;
    end;
    Writeln(S); { печатаем результат }
  until false;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вызове процедур и функций, аргументы разделяются запятой:

```pascal
FOR k := 1 TO Length(arg) DO
    arg[k] := Decrypt(arg[k], 2);
```

Comment: Спасибо, и как я мог забыть?

Comment: @Влад Если ответ вас устраивает, следует отметить его как верный, нажав галочку.